# Repeat methods for object of same class

Tags: python, methods, decorator

I would like to create two objects such that methods for some of this objects will be repeated for other. Then I try to do this:

```
def backup(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        getattr(self.another_tester, method.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Tester():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def select_backup(self, tester):
        self.another_tester = tester
    @backup
    def foo1(self, stop=False):
        print("I am tester {}, do method foo1".format(self.name))
    @backup
    def foo2(self, stop=False):
        print("I am tester {}, do method foo2".format(self.name))
    @backup
    def foo3(self, stop=False):
        print("I am tester {}, do method foo3".format(self.name))

tester1 = Tester("A")
tester2 = Tester("B")
tester1.select_backup(tester2)
tester2.select_backup(tester1)
tester1.foo1()
tester2.foo2()
tester1.foo3()
```

I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` for such code. class `Tester` have a lot of different methods (foo1, foo2, foo3, ...), and I would like to `backup` (repeat) each method. So I use decorator.

I can change decorator:

```
def backup(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            kwargs["stop"]
        except KeyError:
            getattr(self.another_tester, method.__name__)(stop=True, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

It's work, but I think there is more pythonic way to do it. Can anyone offer such way?

Comment: What's the desired behavior if there's a longer loop? Should it go only one deep, or should it continue until it repeats? Like, if you've got an A, a B, and a C, and A delegates to B delegates to C delegates to A?

Comment: No, it's supposed only two objects of class Tester in programm. So A delegates to B and B delegates to A. So A is backup for B and B is backup for A.

Comment: Please update your Question with an exampel which explain this _**It's supposted that there will be a lot of methods which would be repeated, so decorator is needed**_

Comment: Thanks, I added example.

Comment: Your backup is trying to delegate to its backup, which is trying to delegate to its backup and so on.

Comment: Are your two objects always going to be instances of the same class (no subclasses)? If so, you could make your wrapper really simple: `method(self, *args, **kwargs); method(self.another_tester, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Yes, it's great! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your pair of objects are always instances of the same class (or at least, never have different implementations of the decorated method), you can change the decorator so that it directly calls the original method on the other instance, rather than getting the decorated version via `getattr`:

```
def backup(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        method(self.another_tester, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If you want to be able to support pairs of objects of different classes (and different method implementations), things need to be a bit more complicated. You can save a reference to the original undecorated method as an attribute on the wrapper function, then look it up when you need it:

```
def backup(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        other_method = getattr(self.another_tester, method.__name__).orig_method
        other_method(self.another_tester, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.orig_method = method
    return wrapper
```